# D3-brush disable SHIFT locking x/y position

Tags: javascript, d3.js

From the documentation of d3-brush (https://alexdeng.github.io/ab-stats/d3/CHANGES/#brushes-d3-brush): 
"Holding down SHIFT (⇧) while brushing locks the x- or y-position of the brush."

How do I turn of this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
When constructing your brush with `brush.call(d3.brush().on(...`
add the `keyModifiers(false)` argument: `brush.call(d3.brush().keyModifiers(false).on(...`

Comment: Just the note, that keyModifiers where added in the version `1.1.0` of package `d3-brush`.